# LINQ Array elements find in join tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables Student and YearAcademy. I am selecting only Student table but joined YearAcademy table with student table.

Suppose, in join YearAcademy table row having roll number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...,99

i want to Search: List rollno = {1,3,5};

How would i pass rollno as list of int values to YearAcademy.rollno field?

Can anyone help me to know how to set where clause searched array list to yearacademy joined table ?

```
public ActionResult AttendanceStudentList(FormCollection form)
        {
            List<ViewModel.StudentViewModel> viewModel = new List<ViewModel.StudentViewModel>();
            string yearacademy = AcademyYear;
            int studentclassid = Convert.ToInt32(form["classid"]);
            string studentdivision = form["division"];
            string rno = "1,3,2";// form["rollno"];
            List<int> rollno = { 1,2,3,4};// new List<int>(rno.Split(','));

        string grno = form["grno"];

        using (var context = new emsEntities())
        {
            var DataTable = from YearAcademy in context.tbl_YearAcademy
                            join Student in context.tbl_Student
                            on YearAcademy.Id_Student equals Student.Id_Student 
                            where
                                 (YearAcademy.FromToYear == yearacademy)
                            where
                                 (YearAcademy.Id_ClassLevel == studentclassid)  && rollno.Contains(YearAcademy.RollNo.Value.ToString()))


                            select 
                             Student;

            foreach (var iModel in DataTable)
            {

                tbl_Student obj = iModel;
                StudentViewModel vm = new StudentViewModel();
                vm = ParseObject(vm, iModel);
                viewModel.Add(vm);

            }


        }
        ViewBag.Class = studentdivision;

        return PartialView("StudentAttendanceList", viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var DataTable = from YearAcademy in context.tbl_YearAcademy
                join Student in context.tbl_Student
                on YearAcademy.Id_Student equals Student.Id_Student 
                where YearAcademy.FromToYear == yearacademy &&
                      YearAcademy.Id_ClassLevel == studentclassid  &&  
                      rollno.Contains(YearAcademy.RollNo)
                select Student;
```

You don't have to call the `ToString()` method on `YearAcademy.RollNo.Value`.  Also, you have to change the declartion of `rollno` to the following one:

```
List<int?> rollno = { 1,2,3,4 };
```